# set margin 7 mm from left lineno internal line numbers

Tags: line-numbering, pseudocode, lineno

I am trying to set a 7 mm margin from the left on my pseudocode. I am using lineno package and this is what I wrote:

```
\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{alltt}{\footnotesize{\internallinenumbers
S = \(\emptyset\)
while ((not ottimo(S) ) and (C \(\ne\) \(\emptyset\)))
    x = seleziona(C)
    C = C – \{x\}
    if (ammissibile(S U \{x\}))
        S = S U \{x\}
if (ottimo(S))
    return S
else
    return \(\emptyset\)
}}
\end{alltt}

\lipsum[2-4]
```

How can I set the margin to 7 mm from the beginning of the paragraph so it doesn't look different from the rest of the document?

For example:
I get this as output:

```
     blablabla
     blablabla
1   pseudocode line1
2   pseudocode line2
     blablabla
     blablabla
```

Instead of this:

```
blablabla
blablabla
1   pseudocode line1
2   pseudocode line2
blablabla
blablabla
```

Image of the wrong output:[image: wrong]

To be clear, I want "1" right under "nibh" and not moved to the left

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Please add a [minimal **working** example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: I added things, hoping it makes it clear what I am trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad news is that you can't put `alltt` into a `minipage`.  However, since it is implemented as a list, you can nest it with other lists.  Rather than create a new list to achieve the desired indentation, I just used a `quote` environment.

The location of the line numbers (right side) is controlled by `\linenumbersep`.  You have to guess how wide to make it to align the first digit.  Even `\settowidth{...}{\tiny 10}` was too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE nly

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{quote}\linenumbersep=-5pt
\begin{alltt}\footnotesize\internallinenumbers
S = \(\emptyset\)
while ((not ottimo(S) ) and (C \(\ne\) \(\emptyset\)))
    x = seleziona(C)
    C = C – \{x\}
    if (ammissibile(S U \{x\}))
        S = S U \{x\}
if (ottimo(S))
    return S
else
    return \(\emptyset\)
\end{alltt}
\end{quote}

\lipsum[2-4]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: That's great!! Thank you very much